# DIVs repeating in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, repeat

Here is the source:

http://store.bionoricausa.com/index.aspx

All good in FF and Mac browsers.

In IE8 developer mode, the 3 divs immediately below div id="footerIn" are shown being recreated a second time, resulting in a repeating footer.

This is with Compatibility Mode off.

When it is on, the repeating problem is gone, but the header logo is missing.

This page is a port of a WordPress site as home page to a Network Solutions e-commerce site. As you probably know, NS auto-generates a container and table around the header, body, and footer content, interfering with any of your own containers that you may have used in another CMS. I suspect this is most of my problem, as I've had to develop workarounds to display parts of the page properly to match the original WP site. But no matter how I rearrange the footer code, I can't get IE8 to stop doubling it.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without going through all your markup, I can say I've seen this kind of problem before on IE and it's typically caused by: a tag that wasn't closed, tags that weren't nested propertly, or an extraneous closing tag somewhere. That's where I would start first.

Comment: Thanks - I did validate the page and what is amiss are all the header links, as Network Solutions pushes these further down the page when you add them into the "header" area of the CMS, so there's nothing I can do about those.

Comment: The other issue is where NS starts and ends it's Form, which the whole page becomes, but again, I can't edit that as it is auto-generated. Aside from those items, I can't find incorrectly nested tags...

Comment: Is it actually messing up any of the tags nesting or closing properly?

Comment: Some tags show as invalid in DW, but I have rechecked them numerous times. All tags are closed and apparently in the right place and they validate...any ideas?

Comment: Unless there are specific IE8 bugs re: start and stop points of forms - the problem divs are immediately after a small form, and the position of the larger form is probably causing the problem tags to look like problems when they're not...the small form was originally not in tags, I put it inside a div, but no difference...the overall page form I can't edit as it is auto-generated

Comment: Well, I don't know what's causing it yet, but to narrow the problem down, I'd probably start with your footer and start removing nested elements until you can find some kind of correlation. It seems likely the problem is around that area (although obviously not for certain.)

Comment: Yes - thanks - I have been doing just that for longer than I care to remember :) - I can't get the DW highlighted tags to clear up unless I delete them...and they are necessary - I can try some more, but I've been on this for over a day already which is why I posted - it's my first post and the first time I haven't been able to solve something in a "reasonable" amount of time...but I can look again

Comment: The first "problem" tag is the container and table tags auto-generated by Network Solutions - these are causing the problem, but they are irremovable.

Comment: So it seems like it's just a matter of working around the trouble the NS tags might be causing then?

Comment: At this point, I'm stumped...I'm going to try once more to elimate the whole footer section, then add in elements one by one and see if I can find the one IE doesn't like by elimination, and if that doesn't work, I will probably try to construct the footer a different way with less images and CSS backgrounds and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

It was the fact that there was a search form in the footer tag - Network Solutions creates a form, container, and table to put the whole page in, so the search form that was part of the page I imported from WordPress wouldn't work (you can't have a form within a form). That is what IE objected to. The nested form caused all the footer tags to go haywire in DW, but DW didn't highlight the form as being a problem at all, just all the divs around it...

Thanks kinakuta for your help.